# JAVA MULTI DIM ARRAY COLUMN & ROW TOTAL, OUTPUT

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Write a program that stores the weekly (Monday thru Friday) sales totals for three salespersons. Your program should allow the user to enter the sales amounts and print a sales report with headings, the daily totals for each salesperson (your two-dimensional array), the calculated weekly totals for each sales person and the calculated totals for the day of each salesperson. In addition, create a single-dimensional array of Strings representing the days of the week (Monday-Friday) using an initializer list.

NEED HELP ON GETTING THIS OUTPUT AND CALCULATING ROW & COLUMN TOTALS

```
 Weekly Sales Report

      Mon     Tue     Wed    Thurs    Fri       Total

1    10.00   20.00   30.00   40.00   50.00      150.00

2    60.00   70.00   80.00   90.00   10.00      310.00

3    20.00   30.00   40.00   50.00   60.00      200.00

--------------------------------------------------------------

     90.00  120.00   150.00  180.00 120.00      660.00



import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimArray
{
public static void main( String [] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

    // 1) Declare and allocate Storage

    String [] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
    double [][] saleTotals = new double [3][5];

    // 2) Populate Array

   for (int i = 0; i < saleTotals.length; i++ )
    for ( int j = 0; j < saleTotals[0].length; j++ )
    {
      System.out.print( "Enter " + days[j] + " Totals for Salesperson " + (i+1) + ": " + "  " );
      saleTotals[i][j] = scan.nextDouble( );

    }

     // 3) Process Array - Accumulators
    double total = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < saleTotals.length; i++ )
        for ( int j = 0; j < saleTotals[0].length; j++ )
        total += saleTotals[i][j];



    System.out.println( );
    System.out.println(" Weekly Sales Report ");

     // 4) Output Array
    for ( int i = 0; i < saleTotals.length; i++ )
    {
         System.out.println();
        for ( int j = 0; j < saleTotals[0].length; j++ )
        {
        System.out.print(saleTotals[i][j] + "\t");
        }
    }

    System.out.println( );
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");


    System.out.println( total);
```

THIS IS HOW FAR IVE GOTTEN

Answer (score 0):

your array doesn't have items so its length will be 0 you should change the for loops index as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
    {
           .....
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to Java, but looked at this as a challenge, this is how I did it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 Weekly Sales Report

 Mon     Tue     Wed    Thurs    Fri       Total

 1    10.00   20.00   30.00   40.00   50.00      150.00

 2    60.00   70.00   80.00   90.00   10.00      310.00

 3    20.00   30.00   40.00   50.00   60.00      200.00

 --------------------------------------------------------------

      90.00  120.00   150.00  180.00 120.00      660.00

 */

public class WeeklyReportExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] days = new String[] { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri" };
        int[] salesPerson = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        double[][] salesFigures = new double[3][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < salesPerson.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Sales Person " + salesPerson[i] + " :");

            for (int j = 0; j < days.length; j++) {

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Enter daily sales amount for " + days[j]
                        + " : ");
                double dailyAmount;
                dailyAmount = scan.nextDouble();
                salesFigures[i][j] = dailyAmount;
            }
        }

        double[] salesPersonTotal = new double[3];
        double[] dailyTotal = new double[5];
        double overallTotal = 0;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Weekly Sales Totals:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("\t");

        for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {

            System.out.print(days[i] + "\t");
        }

        System.out.print("Total");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        for (int k = 0; k < salesFigures.length; k++) {

            System.out.print(salesPerson[k] + "\t");

            for (int l = 0; l < salesFigures[k].length; l++) {

                salesPersonTotal[k] += salesFigures[k][l];
                dailyTotal[l] += salesFigures[k][l];

                System.out.print(String.format("%.2f", salesFigures[k][l])
                        + "\t");
            }

            overallTotal += salesPersonTotal[k];


            System.out.print(String.format("%.2f", salesPersonTotal[k]));
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("\t");

        for (int m = 0; m < dailyTotal.length; m++) {

              System.out.print(String.format("%.2f", dailyTotal[m]) + "\t");
        }

        System.out.print(String.format("%.2f", overallTotal));

    }

}
```